# Strings boxed with QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP always translated to original string

Tags: qt, macros, translation

I have a .h file that some global constants is defined there. For example the name of product is defined like:

```
#define PRODUCT_NAME QString(QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("QObject", "MyProductName"))
```

The string **MyProductName** is appeared in the *.qs and I translate it as well. When I want to use that variables I tested both below method, but not one returns that translation and always the original text is displayed.

```
// style 1
setWindowTitle(QObject::tr(PRODUCT_NAME));

// style 2
setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("QObject", PRODUCT_NAME));
```

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#define PRODUCT_NAME QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("QObject", "MyProductName")
// style 1
setWindowTitle(QObject::tr(PRODUCT_NAME));
```

`QString tr(const char*)` will return a QString.

Rerun lupdate after changing the code and apply the translation in ts-file, release to qm and include this in your application.